# Parameter Not valid Image Conversion

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, arrays

**Code:**

```
Image imgnew = null;
using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream(img))
{
     imgnew =  Image.FromStream(ms1);
}
```

Getting a `Parameter No valid` while trying to convert binary to image

Read a lot of solution most of them claiming the byte is incorrect where as I generated the code from
this site http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter
and the byte code represents the correct image

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Sorry for the unclear question earlier, was running out of time

As of now I do not have the exact Code but im writing the steps

1. Receiving a String
2. Converting it to byte array using Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64String)
3. and then passing the bye array to the above code

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: tell more about how you've initialized `img`

Comment: What's inside "img"? Obviously it is a byte[], but what does it contain? How do you converting that base64 content to a byte array?

Comment: Yeah, what is the `img`?

Comment: 5 $ on: img = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64String);

Comment: Please post the *exact* nad *full* exception message, including the callstack. Besides, why do you think the data is correct? `FromStream` expecta a valid *binary image* (eg BMP, JPG), not the bytes of a base64 string

Comment: @Oguz -5 if this is ever posted. FromStream is meant to read *image bytes*, not strings. A base64 has nothing in common with the underlying binary data. *If* the base64 text is actually correct, it has to be decoded first to a byte array.

Comment: @Arijit Mukherjee first make sure you *do* have a valid image. Decode the base64 string to a byte array and save it to disk with the proper extension (png, jpg, bmp). Can you open this file with an image viewer?

Comment: Dear @panagiotis-kanavos. You missunderstand my comment. I bet $5 on, that is the mistake he is making, and until he provides the img, bets are on.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen its a byte array
`byte[] img = "data coming from webservice method";`

Comment: @OguzOzgul yes show we not use it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in the exception message it is just this error 

i'm following the steps that you are saying, no its not opening in image viewer I will add additional comment to the question

Comment: So, probably you are receiving that string as base64 encoded. Instead of Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64String), try Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)

Comment: I will hunt for my $5 if this is the issue by the way.

Comment: most probably yes cos i was using the site to convert image to byte64string but i'm not sure whether its already encoded or not

will surely try that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95761/discussion-between-arijit-mukherjee-and-oguz-ozgul).

Comment: Convert.FromBase64String(img)

Sortewd the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned Out To Be an Encoding issue by:

`Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64String)`

Sorted Out by changing it to :

`Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)`

Hope this might be of some help to someone else.